# Identify a WW1 uniform

Tags: identification, world-war-one, india, uniform

[image: a man in a white uniform]

What is this uniform? Photo of my grandfather. I believe he was in the British Army in India during WW1, possibly Army Pay Corps as he was deaf so could not fight. I cannot find anything about the white uniform on the internet and am interested to know what it represents. Does anyone have an idea? I am writing a family history. The uniform is white and looks like it is designed for the tropics.

Comment: if he is british, white could also indicate Naval